# Restoring PG database owned by ordinary user but which requires SU privileges in some places

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to restore a database owned by an ordinary user if some "create function" calls use "language internal" that requires superuser privileges?

Say postgres is a role with superuser privileges, and bob is a normal user. There's a db owned by bob. If I pg_restore the db as -U bob then create function call fails due to lack of permissions. If I pg_restore the db as -U postgres then it succeeds, but every object is owned by user postgres. I tried "create database foo owner=bob" log in there with psql -U postgres, then use one of "set role bob" or "set session authorization bob", but after the statement executes privileges are dropped and the user is unable to create the function. So the only way is to manually precreate the function as superuser and the proceed with pg_restore -U bob, ignoring the failed create function call? I was hoping there would be a way to restore the db as superuser but still mark the created objects as owned by a normal user. Thanks for any tips.

The dump is created using this command:
pg_dump -p 5432 -bF c -n public -Z5 -f '$outfile' --exclude-table-data=foo --exclude-table-data=bar

DB name to dump is taken from PG DATABASE and is foo)

Comment: There must be more to this story.  Setting ownership back to the original user (recorded in the dump) is what pg_restore usually does.

Comment: Looks like you made a backup without the ownership of the database objects. Did you use --no-owner (or -O ) for pg_dump or not?

Comment: It's not an ownership problem, it's just that if the user pg_restore issues statements as (either -U or --role) isn't a superuser the restore fails because "CREATE FUNCTION ... LANGUAGE internal" can only be run as superuser. But since app code eventually using the db doesn't and shouldn't run as superuser, it has problems when running DB migrations as ordinary user, being unable to alter db object definition (schema) owned by superuser.

Comment: It is an ownership issue. To your question add the `pg_dump` command you used to create the dump

Comment: Added it at the end above.

Comment: Why not create a group? [PostgreSQL Manual - 22.3 Role Membership](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/role-membership.html)

Answer (score 0):

False alarm. Counterintuitively running pg_restored as superuser and NOT specifying --role or --no-owner just worked. CREATE FUNCTION .. LANGUAGE internal ran just fine, and all created objects were marked as owned by the non-superuser taken from the dump.